# Can you get trapped in the Naruto dream world?

Tags: anime, naruto, manga

I know that when "*Infinite Tsukuyomi*" is cast, each and every person having chakra is trapped into a dream world.

**What happens to them if the person who controls the dream dies?**

Comment: I know **nothing** about this show but is there any reason to assume that people don't just wake up?

Comment: well that can be assumed. but if there is anything except this

Comment: I don't remember so clearly, but isn't that assumption justified by the fact that when it is cast, the only ones not in it, attack and try to kill the caster, rather than loose the spell?

Comment: While isn't off-topic here, [anime.se] might be a better fit.

Comment: I know generally speaking Genjutsu's fade or stop if the caster dies, though there are exceptions to that rule. I'm currently watching the show for the first time, and I haven't seen this cast yet. So, I'm not sure of the rules on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: The Genjutsu (the dream world) would end and everyone would return to reality.**

---

I'm not an expert in Naruto lore but having read some of the manga and watched the anime:

[image: Homer]

- [Genjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Genjutsu) is used to trick and manipulate the brain's senses and is used for a variety of reasonsn such as information-gathering, offensive/defensive strategy, torture etc.

> Genjutsu is created when a ninja controls the chakra flow of the opponent's cerebral nervous system, thereby affecting their five senses.

Therfore, if the ninja no longer controlled the chakra flow in the opponent, the brain would no longer be affected. Ergo, any illusion created by the Genjutsu would end.

- Genjutsu consumes chakra and can only be performed effectively if the user possesses acute chakra control.

> Genjutsu attacks usually require a lot of skill, and, if performed incorrectly, will not work... Genjutsu is most often used by ninja with very precise chakra control and very high intelligence.

- The *[Infinite Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi)* technique originates from the [**Ten-Tailed Beast**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ten-Tails) who is considered the incarnation of the origin of chakra. In other words, it has the potential of having infinite chakra by absorbing it from its victims by use of the [*God: Nativity of a World of Trees*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/God:_Nativity_of_a_World_of_Trees) technique. Note that for the *Infinite Tsukuyomi* technique to be infinite would require other techniques.
- This was mainly part of [Madara Uchiha's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha) [**Eye of the Moon Plan**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_the_Moon_Plan) to bringing his twisted version of world peace and putting people in a dream-like reality.

So summing up, if the flow of chakra to all victims under the effects of the illusion were broken, there would be no other reason for them to remain under the Genjutsu.

**But don't quote me on this.**